# Sql query the store that has best sell quality in pubs sample database

Tags: sql, sql-server, pubs

In pubs database, I want to query the store in which has highest sales quality.
I exec following query,

```
select stores.stor_id, sum(sales.qty) as sumqty
from stores
join sales on stores.stor_id = sales.stor_id
group by stores.stor_id, stores.stor_name
```

Results:

```
+-------+------+
|stor_id|sumqty|
+-------+------+
|6380   |8     |
+-------+------+
|7066   |125   |
+-------+------+
|7067   |90    |
+-------+------+
|7131   |130   |
+-------+------+
|7896   |60    |
+-------+------+
|8042   |80    |
+-------+------+
```

The result I need is like

```
+-------+------+
|stor_id|sumqty|
+-------+------+
|7131   |130   |
+-------+------+
```

Could you give some suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way, use `SELECT TOP 1` and `ORDER BY DESC`

```
select top 1 sales.stor_id, sum(sales.qty) as sumqty
from stores
join sales on stores.stor_id = sales.stor_id
group by sales.stor_id
order by 2 desc;
```

Anyway, why you need join to `stores`? I think from `sales` table is enough:

```
select top 1 sales.stor_id, sum(sales.qty) as sumqty
from sales
group by sales.stor_id
order by 2 desc;
```

Above query will fail if the result has two or more records as max value.

Use this to handle that:

```
select sales.stor_id, MAX(sumqty) as sumqty from (select sales.stor_id, sum(sales.qty) as sumqty
from sales
group by sales.stor_id) sales
```

Comment: The reason I join stores is that I want to get store detail information such as store name. You first two queries are work, but as I know, keyword TOP only supported by SQL Server. I hope query is portable. Last query are not work. It fails with message "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "sales.stor_id" could not be bound."

Comment: Thanks for your update, but I'm sorry that your newest query still not work with error message "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'sales.stor_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.stor_id, max(sumqty)
From (

select sales.stor_id, sum(sales.qty) as sumqty
from stores
join sales on stores.stor_id = sales.stor_id
group by sales.stor_id

) a 
Group by a.stor_id
```

Just in case you have two stores with the same sales qty

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!